# htaccess redirect http://subdomain.example.com to www.subdomain.example.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am able to redirect my site http://example.com to www.example.com using below code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com <br />
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But not getting solution for http://subdomain.example.com to www.subdomain.example.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```